# How to change a php script value, depending on time?

Tags: php, datetime

*First of all I am not an expert in php.*

I have a url redirecting script.
It works by fetching links from a .txt database
I want to chnage that database depending on time.
For example run "db1.txt" from 6AM to 1:59PM
and run "db2.txt" from 2PM to 5:59AM.

The redirecting script has the following line to address the databse.

```
$db = 'db.txt';
```

The following didnt work

```
$time  = date("H:i", strtotime("$time"));
echo $time;
if ($time >= 6 && $hour <= 14)
{
$db = db1.txt;
}
else
{
$db = db2.txt;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only check the hour you don't need `:i` inside `date()`. Check the [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) to find out all `date()` parameters.

Additionally you will get a syntax error at `$db = db1.txt;` and `$db = db2.txt;` because you are missing quotes.

`strtotime("$time")` looks wrong to me. I guess you want the current timestamp using `time()`

Change the code like this:

```
$time = date("H", time());
echo $time;

if ($time >= 6 && $time <= 14)
{
    $db = 'db1.txt';
}
else
{
    $db = 'db2.txt';
}
```

Comment: thanks for teh reply. The "echo $time;" has been showing "18" for the last 3-4 hours !! any idea why ?

Comment: Is it your browser cached for displaying the 18?

Comment: I guess he wants to use `time()` to get the current timestamp

Comment: @modsfabio, thanks your script worked. I will do more tests on it now.
George Peter, it was my script's issue, modsfabio fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you just use the time , you can easily define using file in one line with the ternary operator !

If you can your current server time :

```
$db = (date('H') >= 6 && date('H') < 14) ? 'db1.txt' : 'db2.txt';
```

Or if you can define the time :

```
$defineDate = date('H', strtotime($myTime));
$db = ($defineDate >= 6 && defineDate < 14) ? 'db1.txt' : 'db2.txt';
```

Don't forget to use **correctly** the conditions :

```
($defineDate >= 6 && defineDate < 14) // To 6 to 13:59:59
($defineDate >= 6 && defineDate <= 14) // To 6 to 14:00:00
```

Official PHP documentation for : 
    - [PHP Date function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
    - [PHP Strtotime function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)
    - [PHP Ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)